Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiskit-ibm-runtime
I get: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qiskit-ibm-runtime when trying to load: pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime.
qiskit-ibm-runtime is not listed when I do a pip list and python3 --version gives Python 3.6.9
qiskit seems to be installed OK
Please help,
thanks, John

I was running into this same issue on an M3 Mac running Sonoma 14.1. My Python version was also 3.6. I upgraded to Python 3.7 and was able to install the package.
